# Netbeans JavaEE ICEFace basic webpage

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, icefaces

(Feel free to skip the first two paragraphs :) I know this goes against some people's programming religion, but oh well: I know nothing about building JavaEE web apps and using ICEFaces in Netbeans. However, I've been handed a website that implements this and I need to add a new page to it with basic functionality. I know the java programming language, but that's it (JavaSE). I figured I could just use the site's existing pages as a reference to creating my own very basic page. I've come to find its not that simple.
I don't really understand the concept. Connecting to existing pages from the browser ends in an `example.iface` extension when there's no example.iface file in the site, which I don't get, but that's okay.. The files that support the webpage end in `example.jsp` and `example.java`. Regardless, I made my own two files, `myPage.jsp` and `myPage.java`, and placed them in the same location as the other existing files, and used the same code in reference to make a very basic "Hello World" webpage. I try linking to a `myPage.iface` like the others, and I get a blank page.
I realize I need a basic understanding of the concepts of how this all works, so I created a new project just to get a 'Hello World' webpage working. The way these projects are setup is so confusing to me and I'm looking all over google for beginner tutorials on this and I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone baby-step me through creating an `.iface` "Hello World" page, starting from File->New Project (>_<) I will be forever in your debt! THX

Comment: Baby steps: [JSF @ The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html)

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the link, post as answer if you want and I'll vote up. I'm still working at it tho.. JavaEE facelets makes me feel retarded..like I'm starting my web dev. education all over again ><

Comment: @Matt This tutorial tells me to create a Hello.java file and a beanhello.xhtml file that references the backing bean. I still can't figure out how to do what I mentioned: link to my .jsp page via extension .iface, like the rest of the files are. I've looked through the web.xml and see a general *.iface URL pattern in a servlet, so I guess its not a page by page configuration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baby steps: [JSF @ The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html).

---

I can take a look at your question in the comments later, but you can really just post a new question and get an answer from others on the site much sooner.